# Why is Wolfram missing so many oblique asymptotes? (Not only about Wolfram in thread)

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Few days ago I made a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006572/am-i-to-place-my-trust-in-wolfram-on-this-matter-oblique-asymptotes-on-a-funct), and to be frank I'm not sure if I'm even having this question in the right forum. But I'm also looking for information on if my thoughts are correct.

Observe [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptotes%20%28e%5E%28-1%2Fx%29*x*arctan%28x%29%29) little plotted function. Do you agree with me that there should be two and **NOT** one oblique asymptote? If not, why?

I want to find the constant for the asymptote Wolfram did **NOT** catch; how can I do this using Wolfram in perhaps a different way? (I do also have Mathematica if that helps).

Comment: What are you expecting the second oblique asymptote to be?

Comment: @Arkamis I'm expecting it to have a negative slope, and a constant value *near* zero, as one can see in the linked graph. I.e. the curve left of the y-axis.

Comment: Indeed it has one, I will provide an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Wolfram Alpha only looks for oblique asymptotes as $x\to +\infty$.

You can find the other asymptote by substituting $x\mapsto -x$ by hand and ask for [asymptotes of the mirrored function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptotes+%28e%5e%281%2Fx%29%2a-x%2aarctan%28-x%29%29) instead.

Comment: *shakes an angry fist* :)

Comment: @Arkamis :þ ${}$

Comment: I think @HenningMakholm won by a few seconds. Thanks fellas

Answer (score 2):

The function does indeed have another asymptote. I don't know why W|A doesn't provide it.

To find it, simply apply the mapping $x \mapsto -x$, *viz.* [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptotes+%28-e%5E%281%2Fx%29*x*arctan%28-x%29%29).